# Spring Select tag breaks my HTML page

Tags: java, spring, select, jstl

I am trying to use the simplest Spring select tag ever - all it needs to do is have 2 choices one for black and one for white, with the proper tags in place everything that is below the tag renders to white space - very frustrating.

In my jsp I have this with my import at the page header

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<form:select path="productColor">
    <form:option value="default" label="--Select color"></form:option>
    <form:options items="${colorsMap}"></form:options>
</form:select>
```

My controller has the following code

```
Map< String, String > colors = new HashMap();
colors.put("black", "BLACK");
colors.put("white", "WHITE");
model.addObject("colorsMap", colors);
```

the path corresponds to my model object with property "productColor"

What am I doing wrong? I have tried many variations, followed many tutorials and examples, I am doing everything to a T with no luck everytime I get a white space on my entire page below where the select tag is being used......please help.

Comment: can you post some printscreen ?

Comment: @user3924466 is your path `productColor` available in `commandObject`, look for the errors in server logs

Comment: After further investigation if I remove this tag - <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>   then the page looks normal again, what is wrong with that tag?

Comment: @user3924466 there should be some errors in the server logs when that `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` is present in your jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - it had to do with my project setup, the command object is only exposed if the user is logged in my fault.